# Does the function $f\circ g(x) = (f\circ g)(x)$ have same properties?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Is $f\circ g(x) = (f\circ g)(x)$? Do they have similar properties on how they work as a functions.

The function $(f\circ g)(x)$ is equal to $f(g(x))$. But I am unaware on how $f\circ g(x)$ works.

My guess is that $f\circ g(x)$ is the same as $(f\circ g)(x)$ since you compose the $x$ in $(f\circ g)(x)$ together to achieve $f \circ g(x)$. But a problem that i noticed that if we compose $(f\circ g)(x)$ it together as I stated to get $f\circ g(x)$, it would also imply that you can achieve $f(x)\circ g$

Due to that problem, I am unaware what is the appropriate answer. Furthermore, I am unable to find anything online.

Comment: Well... what do you think?

Comment: @LordVader007 I updated it

Comment: I believe it is notation for the same thing. For example, you have $f(x) = sin(x)$ and $g(x) = log(x)$, so $f(g(x))= sin(log(x))$. Writing $(sin \circ log)(x)$ is same as saying $sin \circ log(x)$.

Comment: The o in fog(x) is the sign of composition and x is not multiplied. Functions are not multiplied by the argument but the whole composition is operated on x.

Comment: @SNEHILSANYAL i am aware that is a composition and I will fix that immediately

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $f\circ g (x) $ means $f\circ (g (x)) $ and this is, generally, different from $(f\circ g)(x) $.
Indeed, $f\circ g (x) $ is a function when $g (x) $ is a function.
More precisely, let $g:X\to Z^Y $ and $f:Z\to W $.
Then for all $x\in X$ we have $g (x):Y\to Z $ hence $f\circ g (x):Y\to W $ and
$$(f\circ g (x))(y)=f (g (x)(y)) $$